# Self-Join in Pandas producing unwanted Duplicates

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have data in a Pandas dataframe in the format:

`CompanyA, CompanyB, Currency, Item, Amount`

Typical rows might be:

```
Microsoft,Oracle,USD,Item_X,252.23
Microsoft,Oracle,USD,Item_Y,234.23
Microsoft,Oracle,EUR,Item_X,23352.00
Microsoft,Oracle,EUR,Item_Y,23344.80
Microsoft,IBM,GBP,Item_X,123.12
Microsoft,IBM,GBP,Item_Y,432.12
Oracle,IBM,EUR,Item_X,999.23
Oracle,IBM,EUR,Item_Y,234.23
```

Amount if a float, the others are strings.

I want to expand the Item column out so each Item entry gets its own column, which now contains the Amount.  Basically make the data wider, rather than longer.

```
CompanyA, CompanyB, Currency, Item_X, Item_Y

Microsoft,Oracle,USD,252.23, 234.23
Microsoft,Oracle,EUR,,23352.00,23344.80
... and so on.
```

It feels like it should be a self-join - and I've tried things like:

```
df = pd.merge(df, df, on=['CompanyA', 'CompanyB', 'Currency'])
```

This produces almost the right output, but it joins each row 4 times:

```
Item_X -> Item_X
Item_X -> Item_Y
Item_Y -> Item_X
Item_Y -> Item_Y
```

Obviously I'm only interested in Item_X -> Item_Y.

In SQL you would further contrain the query, and this is where I'm getting stuck - how do this in Pandas?  Or is there an easier approach!

Cheers!

Phil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['CompanyA','CompanyB','Currency','Item'])['Amount']
       .unstack()
       .reset_index()

print (df)
Item   CompanyA CompanyB Currency    Item_X    Item_Y
0     Microsoft      IBM      GBP    123.12    432.12
1     Microsoft   Oracle      EUR  23352.00  23344.80
2     Microsoft   Oracle      USD    252.23    234.23
3        Oracle      IBM      EUR    999.23    234.23
```

Or if duplicates need [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with aggregate function:

```
print (df)
    CompanyA CompanyB Currency    Item    Amount
0  Microsoft   Oracle      USD  Item_X    252.23
1  Microsoft   Oracle      USD  Item_Y    234.23
2  Microsoft   Oracle      EUR  Item_X  23352.00
3  Microsoft   Oracle      EUR  Item_Y  23344.80
4  Microsoft      IBM      GBP  Item_X    123.12
5  Microsoft      IBM      GBP  Item_Y    432.12
6     Oracle      IBM      EUR  Item_X    999.23
7     Oracle      IBM      EUR  Item_Y     10.00 <-same values, only Amount different
8     Oracle      IBM      EUR  Item_Y     20.00 <-same values, only Amount different


df = df.pivot_table(index=['CompanyA','CompanyB','Currency'],
                    columns='Item', 
                    values='Amount', 
                    aggfunc='mean').reset_index()
print (df)
Item   CompanyA CompanyB Currency    Item_X    Item_Y
0     Microsoft      IBM      GBP    123.12    432.12
1     Microsoft   Oracle      EUR  23352.00  23344.80
2     Microsoft   Oracle      USD    252.23    234.23
3        Oracle      IBM      EUR    999.23     15.00
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I wanted.  I was *so* close with the pivot solution, but did not specify an aggfunc, simply because for my data set an aggfunc doesn't make sense.  As duplicated can't exist, I can put anything for the aggfunc and the results are valid.... however I'm assuming if there are no duplicates it is probably faster to run the unstack??

Comment: Yes, exactly. Faster is first solution, but if duplicates it raise error. then is possible use another solution.